# Use different base url's with central axios create

Tags: vue.js, axios

In my vue app, in terms of structure, the logic is similar to this great project. It means that in my `src` folder i have a `utils` folder which holds a file `request.js` and inside this file i create my axios instance:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_API
})
```

this instance is then being used across the entire project when i want to commit HTTP request. for example:

```
import request from "@/utils/request";
request({
        url: `/some/dummy/endpoint`,
        method: "get"
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

problem occurs when in few specific places i need to commit HTTP request where the `baseURL` is not `process.env.BASE_API` but `process.env.SECOND_BASE_API`.
axios is available and i can just use it as follows:

```
   this.axios
    .get(`${process.env.SECOND_BASE_API}/api/profile`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

but i wonder if there is a more elegant way to tackle this issue, maybe create another instance? structure my project differently ?  any other insight??
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could easily create a second instance of axios just like you did for your `request` service.

If I were you (note that this is purely opinion based), I would name my request services using the API name. I would have `mainApi` and `secondaryApi`. Or `weatherApi` and `translateApi`:

**utils/mainApi.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const service = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_API
})

export default service
```

**utils/secondaryApi.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const service = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.SECOND_BASE_API
})

export default service
```

You will then be able to use the apis in your components like this:

```
import mainApi from "@/utils/mainApi"

mainApi({
    url: `/some/dummy/endpoint`,
    method: "get"
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

And for your secondary API:

```
import secondaryApi from "@/utils/secondaryApi"

secondaryApi({
    url: `/some/dummy/endpoint`,
    method: "get"
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

The important thing to note here is that `axios.create(...)` creates a completely different instance of axios and that options that you configure for each instance is separated